# Replace using Script in C#

Tags: c#, ssis, c#-3.0

How can i read a certain portion of a text file and replace with another line?

Like in the file there is a part :"Attend_10" want to replace it with "Attend_10_[Variable_Value].

How can i Do this using script (C#) in SSIS?

Comment: In the file there is a part :

<File Name>=Attend_10

I want the following one:

<File Name>=Attend_10_201410

Variable Value is the period value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what your inputs are, or requirements for matching, but you could easily use Linq or a `for` loop to perform this. Below are two simple examples that read an input file `sample.txt` and write to an output file `out.csv`.

**Using Linq:**

```
string periodValue = "201410";
File.WriteAllLines(
    "out.txt",
    File.ReadAllLines("sample.txt").
        Select(l => l.Replace("Attend_10", "Attend_10_" + periodValue))
    );
```

**Using a `for` loop:**

```
string periodValue = "201410";
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("sample.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("Attend_10", "Attend_10_" + periodValue);
}
File.WriteAllLines("out.txt", lines);
```

**Input: sample.txt:**

```
<SomeTextHere>
<File Name>=Attend_10
<MoreTextHere>
```

**Output: out.txt**

```
<SomeTextHere>
<File Name>=Attend_10_201410
<MoreTextHere>
```

If your matching requirements are more advanced, you can use RegEx to match certain patterns in each string.

Comment: Is it possible to replace multiple words without regEx?

Comment: @SaNa3819: Yes. You can do it using multiple assignments or combine them into one line like this: `l.Replace("Attend_10", "Attend_10_"+  periodValue").Replace("Sample_1", "Sample_2")`