# SSIS - Scrub CSV before Loading it

Tags: csv, ssis

I've a CSV with a couple of carriage returns in a column because of which it is breaking into another row, when loaded. I know that we can use an expression to replace those carriage returns. But how can I do it before it the CSV is loaded into the file source?

Comment: I've done this in the past by creating a VBScript to find / replace known bad strings. Are you able to identify the difference between a valid an invalid carriage return? What language / platform would you prefer? Some examples would be VBScript, Powershell, SSIS Script Task (C#)

Comment: C# appears good. To add more info, the CSV has 13 columns and two among them have text like: A likes B \n B likes C \n But C doesn't like A.

Comment: You need to come up with a reliable algorithm to identify the data. If it is always the same piece of data then you can simply use a command lie tool like fnr.exe to find and replace the bad data with good data.

Comment: Here's some samples on how to find and replace. You should drop a script task on your page and have try. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053675/replace-using-script-in-c-sharp http://sql-bi-dev.blogspot.com.au/2010/09/ssis-script-task-to-find-and-replace.html

Answer (score 0):

CR is not the same as LF. In windows a new line is defined by using both CR-LF. Please confirm that you have CR-CR together in a column.

Use the 'Row delimeter' property in your connection to the flat file.

[image]

Comment: Yes I have {CR}{LF}. That row delimiter is gonna cut off at the text in the column where it sees {CR}; and push into a new row.

Comment: @SharatShastri is not a list of delimiters, is the combination of the two. a single CR should not create a new line with these settings in the screenshot.